# __DataBind__control found by FxCop code analysis in ASP.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-analysis, fxcop, static-code-analysis

I use Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite in a website project and want to use the built-in code analysis feature (FxCop). When checking the naming rules, I get this error:

> CA1709: Microsoft.Naming: Korrigieren Sie die Schreibweise von "control" im Membernamen "'module_readPost_ascx.__DataBinding__control15(Object, EventArgs)'"
>
> meaning: I have to check the spelling of the word "control" in member name "'module_readPost_ascx.__DataBinding__control15(Object, EventArgs)'"

Unfortunatly there is no method called __DataBinding__control15(Object, EventArgs) in the whole project. I suppose this code is generated at compile time, so FxCop can find it as it is inspecting the compiled assemblies.

It is found about 150 times in the project, so I want to tell FxCop to ignore this code or change my code to not causing this "exception".

"Not checking rule Microsoft.Naming CA1709" is not an option ;)

Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, according to Microsoft Connect this a (known) bug in Visual Studio. Workaround provided by Microsoft: "As a workaround, you can apply a suppression in the global suppression file for this warning."